# If $W,W^\perp$ are invariant under $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, $char(A)=\mu_A=\mu_{A|W}\mu_{A^T|W^\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

The full exercise is as follows:

> Let $W$ be an invariant subspace of a matrix $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$. Let $\mu_A$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Prove the following:
>
> (a) $W^\perp$ is an invariant under $A^T$, where $A^T$ is the transpose matrix of $A$.
>
> (b) $f_A(x) = f_{A|_W}(x)f_{A^T|_{W^\perp}}(x)$, where $A|_W$ is the restriction of the linear transformation $A$ to $W$.

I solved (a) as follows:

> Take $w \in W, w' \in W^\perp$; $Aw \in W$ since $W$ is $A$-invariant. Using the inner product and the adjoint operator $^*$, $0 = (Aw|w') = (w')^*(Aw) = (A^*w')^*w = (w|A^*w')$; since $A$ is a real matrix, the adjoint operator is the transpose. Then, $(w,A^Tw') = 0 \implies A^Tw' \in W^\perp$, and therefore $W^\perp$ is $A^T$-inveriant.

The argument I have in mind for (b) is that since $W \oplus W^\perp$ is the entire space then, if $\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B}'$ are bases for $W, W^\perp$, the matrix of $A$ in the basis $\mathcal{B} \cup \mathcal{B}'$ has block form

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}A|_W&0\\0&A^T_{W^\perp}\end{array}\right]$$

and so by inspection $f_A = f_{A|_W} f_{A^T_{W^\perp}}$.

Does this hold water? If so, is it rigorous enough? Is there a better approach?

---

**Edit**: Alternate potential approach for (b): $A|_W$ and $A^T|_{W^\perp}$ are diagonalizable with respect to some orthogonal bases since they are $W$- and $W^\perp$-invariant, respectively. Then, since $W \oplus W^\perp$ is the entire space, we take the diagonal block matrix with diagonal blocks the diagonalizations of these two diagonalized operators, and the result follows.

**Edit 2**: $W \oplus W^\perp$ is not necessarily the entire space, so neither of these approaches will work.

Comment: Use Gram Schmidt to see that the orthogonal sum **is** the entire space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missed detail. The matrix   $A$  takes the form

$$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}A|_W&B\\0&C\end{array}\right]$$
since $W^\perp$ isn't invariant subspace by $A$ so we get

$$A^T=\left[\begin{array}{cc}A^T|_W&0\\B^T&C^T\end{array}\right]$$
hence we see that $C^T=A^T|_W^\perp$ and using that $\det(C-xI)=\det(C^T-xI)$ we get the desired result.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, thank you. But, what about the fact that we might not have $W \oplus W^\perp$ be the entire space? In that case, could we not have that $C^T \neq A^T|_{W^\perp}$?

Comment: In finite dimensional space this direct sum is always the entire space.